# Vector Space Problems

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a few vector space problems and I wondering if anyone could tell me whether I am correct / guide me to the right answer.

Instructions: Let u, v, and w be vectors in ${R}^3$ and consider W = w + span {u + v}.

(a) If u, v, and w where the vectors (1,2,−1), (3,0,1), and (7,0,2), exhibit three different vectors in W.

Me: We know that the span of two vectors u,v is going to be = {$cu + c_1v$} where c and $c_1 \in R$. To this we can add 'w' which we can think of as a shift. 
Thus our formula would be W = (7,0,2) + $c(1,2,-1) + c_1(3,0,1)$ Now we just pick a $c$ and $c_1$ and we will get vectors here.

(b) Considering u, v and w as in item (a), describe all the vectors in W.

Me: I believe this problem has the same solution as (a) can't I just say that the vectors in W are described by the form of w + {$cu + c_1v$}? or is there anything else I can include.

(c) Considering u, v and w as in item (a), is it possible to classify W as a geometric object that you know (e.g., a point, line, plane, etc.)? Justify.

Me: If we look at the case we were given and analyze our vectors u,v, and w. We can tell that u, and v are linearly independent therefore their span will be a plane.

They are linearly independent because (0,0,0) = $\alpha(1,2,-1) + \beta(3,0,1)$
When we solve this we get that $\alpha = \beta = 0$.

Basically we have W = $w$ + a plane. We can then think of w as just a shift and we can say that with the span of u and v we get a plane.

(d) In the general setting, how many possibilities are there to classify W as a known geometric object? Justify.

We have a few possibilities:

Possibility 1: Suppose that $u$ and $v$ = (0,0,0) then we will only have w which is a point that can be represented as a line from the origin to it.

Possibility 2: Suppose that $u$ or $v$ = (0,0,0), then we will only have the span of the other vector $v$ or $w$, plus the shift caused by the addition of w. Therefore we could have a line.

Possibility 3: Suppose that $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent (our case in (c), we will produce a plane that is shifted up w units.

Possibility 4 : Suppose that $u$ and $v$ are linearly dependent once again we will have a line just line explained in possibility 2.

(e) In the general setting, can W be a subspace of $R^3$? If your answer is affirmative, find necessary and sufficient conditions for W to be a subspace of $R^3.$

Me:
No, because if we analyze W = $w$ + span$(c,v)$ this would not be closed under addition due to the possibility of $w$ being outside of the span

Thank you for any comments and suggestions. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For (a), note that the span of $u+v$ is a 1-dimensional space spanned by the vector that is the sum of $u$ and $v$

Comment: $W$ is not spanned by the three vectors. It’s not even a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. Re-read its definition carefully.

Comment: You are 100% correct I noticed my error and will edit my problem soon with a different approach